# AngularJS - Unknown provider: AuthProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to redirect users to a login page if they make an attempt to access pages that require them to be logged in. I am using Firebase and AngularJS, following [this guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html). The [error explanation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthProvider%20%3C-%20Auth%20%3C-%20currentAuth) on the AngularJS site indicates that either a non-existent definition or duplicate definition is causing the issue but I cannot identify either of these in my code. Additionally, the stack trace of the error doesn't indicate which of my files caused the error, only mentioning the angular.js file.
Can anyone give me some insight as to what is causing this issue?

Note: The site runs without errors and users can log in and out if I leave out the resolve section of the $routeProvider.

Here is my app.js

```
angular.module('richWebApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'objectFilter'])
.constant('fb', {
  url: 'https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/' //name removed for security reasons
})
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
        if(error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
            $location.path("/login");
        }
    });
})
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/login/login.html'
        }).
        when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/main/main.html',
            resolve: {
                "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                    return Auth.$requireAuth();
                }]
            }
        }).
        when('/thread/:threadId', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/thread/thread.html',
            resolve: {
                "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                    return Auth.$requireAuth();
                }]
            }
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
    });
});
```

Here is the main.js controller

```
angular.module('richWebApp')
.controller('mainPageController', function($scope, $location, userService, currentAuth, threadService, fb, $firebaseAuth, $filter){

    $scope.user = userService.getLoggedInUser();

    $scope.newThreadTitle = '';
    $scope.threadSubject = ''

    $scope.createNewThread = false;

    $scope.sortBy = 'dateAdded'

    $scope.threads = threadService.getAllThreads();

    $scope.getSubjects = function(subject) {
        return $scope.threads.subject;
    }

    $scope.beginAddThread = function() {
        $scope.createNewThread = true;
    }

    $scope.addThread = function(){  
        if(!$scope.newThreadTitle || !$scope.newThreadSubject){
            return false;
        }

        var date = new Date();

        var newThread = {       
            title: $scope.newThreadTitle,
            subject: $scope.newThreadSubject,
            username: $scope.user.name,
            numComments: 0,
            comments: [],
            dateAdded: date.getTime()
        };

        $scope.threads.$add(newThread);

        $scope.newThread = '';
        $scope.newThreadTitle = '';
        $scope.newThreadSubject =  '';

        $scope.createNewThread = false; 
    }

    $scope.sortByDate = function() {
        $scope.sortBy = 'dateAdded';
    }

    $scope.sortByPopularity = function() {
        $scope.sortBy = 'numComments';
    }

    $scope.searchSubject = function(subject) {
        $scope.searchThread = subject;
    }

    $scope.logout = function(){
        userService.logout();
    }

});
```

Here is the thread.js controller

```
angular.module('richWebApp')
.controller('threadPageController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $filter, currentAuth, threadService, fb, userService){

    var threadId = $routeParams.threadId;

    $scope.newComment = '';

    var thread = threadService.getThread(threadId);

    thread.$bindTo($scope, 'thread') 

    $scope.addComment= function(){ 
        if(!$scope.newComment){
            return false; 
        }       

        var currentUser = userService.getLoggedInUser();

        var date = new Date();
        var newComment = {
            text: $scope.newComment,
            username: currentUser.name,
            dateAdded: date.getTime(),
            userPic: currentUser.profilePic        
        };

        $scope.thread.comments = $scope.thread.comments || [];
        $scope.thread.comments.push(newComment);
        $scope.thread.numComments += 1;

        $scope.newComment = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you include the script of the Auth service in your index.html?

Comment: I have the angular-route.js script referenced if that's what you're referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is referring to an Auth factory, which is shown in the example under [Retrieving Authentication State](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-auth-state). Include this in your code.

```
.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("<YOUR FIREBASE>");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);
```